# Can IIS7 be installed on XP?

Tags: iis-7, windows-xp

I'm pretty sure I know the answer to this, but short of a virtual Vista installation, is there a way to install IIS 7 on XP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Which means I'm moving to vista this week as I have to use IIS7.

EDIT: Ha - voted up!  I assume it's a sympathy vote. :-)

Comment: Not a sympathy vote, its just the correct straight forward answer.

Comment: seems you can now with IIS express - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to move to Win 2008 server (setup as workstation see: http://www.win2008workstation.com/wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

Its a completly different model on vista than xp... http.sys and all that type of stuff.  I don't believe you can install IIS 6 on XP.